# How to integrate ReactJS web code with a new React Native project?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, react-native, ionic-framework, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have web application code which is written using react js framework. Now our client wants to create mobile application using hybrid apps concept by having common code base because ift will be easy if client introduce some thing new feature in web , developing for mobile should be minimal challenge. So Is it possible to convert or reuse the web code which is written on react js to react native??

Can anyone please suggest with any coding/project examples.

Can anyone please suggest which hybrid framework i can go for when i have react.js web application code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse some code in both. For example if you and using redux for api, you can reuse the same redux logic for web and native. You can use util functions which are same for web and native. One way is to make seperate repo for the common code and install it in node modules in web and native.